I cant display horizontally of my footer-signature class, i already made the css for it, but somehow it display vertically
I cant display horizontally of my footer-signature class, i already made the css for it, but somehow it display vertically please help
/* note this code is views for pdf export */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Detail Transaksi</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h3 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 2em;
        }

        table th, table td {
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .footer-signature {
            display: flex; 
            justify-content: space-between; 
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 2em;
        }

        .signature-block {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row; 
            align-items: center; 
        }

        .signature-space {
            margin-top: 4em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>PERMOHONAN KEBUTUHAN ALAT TULIS KANTOR (ATK)</h3>
    <h5>Unit: {{ $unit }}</h5>
    <h5>Tanggal: {{ $tanggal }}</h5>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">No</th>
                <th colspan="3">Kebutuhan</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Keterangan</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nama Barang</th>
                <th>Jumlah</th>
                <th>Satuan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($items as $index => $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item['nama_barang'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item['jumlah'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item['satuan'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item['keterangan'] }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Footer Section -->
    <div class="footer-signature">
        <div class="signature-block">
            <div>Pemohon</div>
            <div class="signature-space">(..........................................)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="signature-block">
            <div>Petugas Gudang</div>
            <div class="signature-space">(person name)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="signature-block">
            <div>Operator Persediaan</div>
            <div class="signature-space">(person name)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

i already try everything, even ask for chatGPT, and others AI but still wont work, it's still display vertically not horizontally.
this is the result i want

I adjusted a similar answer
css:
.footer-signature {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.signature-space {
    margin-top: 4em;
}

html:
 <div class="footer-signature">
    <div>
        <div>Pemohon</div>
        <div class="signature-space">
            (..........................................)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>Petugas</div>
        <div class="signature-space">
            (person name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>Operator</div>
        <div class="signature-space">
            (person name)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I changed the flex direction to row and grouped text in divs, thus giving you this look:

space-between sets the three elements far apart, you may change this by different justify-content values, 'center' with proper margin / spacing looks the most similar to what you want.

Firstly, you have to add a flex-direction:row in the footer-signature class. Secondly, adjust some div in the footer to get the output as given image.


.footer-signature {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.signature-space {
    margin-top: 4em;
}
<div class="footer-signature">
    <div>Pemohon</div>
    <div class="signature-space">
        (..........................................)
        <div>Petugas Gudang</div>
    </div>
    <div class="signature-space">
        (person name)
        <div>Operator Persediaan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="signature-space">
        (person name)
    </div>
</div>




I appreciate your answer, but i think you mistaken what i mean, I just edited my question and give the image of the result that i want.  Maybe u can check again and re answer it. thank you

Ah, I see. I hope you already got the answer from @lemon8de
